# Ef Core Cosmos driver + CosmosClient. Unable to read data persisted with CosmosClient using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are using `Ef Core` as our `ORM` to do database operations. As `EF Core Cosmos` do not support bulk inserts to Cosmos, we are also using the `Cosmos Client`. When we do bulk inserts we are using the following code:

```
    public async Task UploadAsync<T>(string databaseName, string containerName, Func<Container, IEnumerable<Task>> dbOperations)
    {
        var instanceUrl = //Commented out
        var primaryKey = //Commented out

        var options = new CosmosClientOptions
        {
            AllowBulkExecution = true,
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway
        };

        using var client = new CosmosClient(instanceUrl, primaryKey, options);
        var container = client.GetContainer(databaseName, containerName);

        var operations = dbOperations(container);

        await Task.WhenAll(operations);
    }
```

This works perfectly and allows us to bulk insert alot of data very quickly into cosmos. Now, we want to read the inserted data with Entity Framework Core with our generic repository pattern:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> ReadAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return await _diagnostics.RunAsync(async () =>
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(CancelRequestAfter);

        var queryable =  _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
        return await queryable.ToListAsync(cts.Token);
    });
}
```

This repository works as expected, but **only** if the entity has been persisted by `EF Core`. However, I can read documents created by `EF Core` with the `Cosmos Client`.

I started looking into why our queries doesn't return anything by comparing the two documents in `Azure Cosmos Data Explorer`. The first document is created using the `Cosmos client` and the second document is created by `EF Core`. The only difference I can spot is that EF Core automatically adds something called `"Discriminator"` to our documents. So I suspect that this is the root cause..

- Can someone verify my thesis? If so, how can I solve this?
- Do `EF Core` have any bulk insert operations like `Cosmos Client`?

Comment: (1) seems to be one of the current [temporary limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/limitations#temporary-limitations) - *"Even if there is only one entity type without inheritance mapped to a container it still has a discriminator property."*. You can try utilizing [HasNoDiscriminator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder-1.hasnodiscriminator?view=efcore-3.1) fluent configuration.

Comment: I will try this and update the question with my findings. Cheers!

Comment: This seems to work as expected! If you like, convert your comment to an answer and I will mark it as accepted.